# XMLHttpRequest response status based on posted value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have my JavaScript function which does XMLHttpRequest. Here is my code.

```
function addbilldetails() {

    // Cancel the form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // The URL to POST our data to
    var postUrl = 'http://example.com/post.php';

    // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);

    // Prepare the data to be POSTed
    var clientId = "clientid",
    submittype = "a",
    name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value),
    billno = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('billno').value),
    mobileno = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('mobileno').value),
    phoneno = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('phoneno').value),
    netAmount = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('netAmount').value);

    var params = 'clientId=' + clientId +
                 '&billno=' + billno + 
                 '&mobileno=' + mobileno + 
                 '&phoneno=' + phoneno +
                 '&netAmount=' + netAmount +
                 '&type=' + submittype +
                 '&name=' + name;

    // Replace any instances of the URLEncoded space char with +
    params = params.replace(/%20/g, '+');

    // Set correct header for form data 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Handle request state change events
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        // If the request completed
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = '';
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // If it was a success, close the popup after a short delay
                statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saved!';
               document.getElementById('save').disabled = false;
                // window.setTimeout(window.close, 1000);
            } else {
                // Show what went wrong
                statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Error saving: ' + xhr.statusText;
            }
        }
    };

    // Send the request and set status
    xhr.send(params);
    statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saving...';
   document.getElementById('save').disabled = true;
}
```

Now, the above code works perfectly and returns `200` on `POST`. But I want it to return custom message on the UI based on the value posted.

If the value `POST`ed is less than the value in the database, I want it to give "Enter Valid number" or something like this.

I am quiet new to `XMLHttpRequest` . I do not know how to achieve that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `statusDisplay.innerHTML = 'Saved!';` have you considered:

```
statusDisplay.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

If you do this, then your statusDisplay will be equal to whatever your `post.php` echos out.

For example, in post.php

```
<?php

//handling $_POST['clientId'] ... etc

if (error)
    echo "Enter Valid Number";
else
    echo "Saved!";
```

Comment: I am getting other garbage values in my error so that is also getting `echo`ed